# Eclipse - eclipse.ini not working

Tags: eclipse, ini, permgen

I have some Eclipse distributions (ADT, Standard, Scala IDE, Modelling + Scala IDE, all downloaded June 2014). I have been experimenting out of permgen memory errors. When trying to solve it, I noticed that eclipse is not taking the arguments provided in the eclipse.ini in at least 2 of the distros. This can be seen in two ways: 1. in the windows process manager, command column, the command does not include the vm arguments. 2. Terminating the java process, the error window that eclipse shows, vm arguments are not included.

For my tests, I am using the same ini file for all distributions. Are there any other variables that affect Eclipse loading and applying vm arguments in ini file?

Note: If I pass the arguments in the console or using a windows shortcut, it works.

Note2: There is no ECLIPSE_HOME env variable defined

Comment: If you specify any vm arguments on the eclipse command line the eclipse.ini vm arguments are ignored.

Comment: I know, I tried it to see if the arguments could get to the vm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little bit of testing, I found the problem. Because I had so many distributions, I had changed the name of the eclipse executable so I could easily find and distinguish them:

`eclipse.exe => some-specific-eclipse.exe`

It turns out that the ini file must have the very same name as the exe:

`eclipse.ini => some-specific-eclipse.ini`

Otherwise, ini file won't be loaded and default configuration will be used. Once you correct the ini file name, everything works as it should

Comment: Thanks this solved a very frustrating issue for me while upgrading Eclipse on Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine so, this one took me days of frustration to figure out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$ECLIPSE_HOME` is set. It will be used before eclipse.ini.

Comment: It is not. I'll keep on testing